# Referencing a file for a certain area of a webpage?

Tags: html, file, reference

Is there any way to make an area of a webpage reference another HTML file? For instance, if I have a sidebar that shows up on every page of my site. Eventually, information on it is going to get changed. Instead of having to go to **every** page to change it, is there a way to make that area of the page another HTML file entirely, and then just reference it, so I only have to edit it once for it to affect the whole site? Thanks!

Comment: Is this straight hand coded HTML or some sort of framework? What are you using for a web server?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not exactly sure what you mean.. This is the first website I've ever coded, and I'm learning as I go. I coded it all by hand. As for web server, do you mean where I purchased my servers? If so, GoDaddy.

Comment: OK. That's fine. It just drives what your tool options are. A quick google suggests GoDaddy has server side includes enabled by default. That's good! It means that BumbleB2na's original server side include answer will work well for you. Hopefully he'll put it back soon.

Comment: Ah, so the iFrame code is how I would do that? I'm assuming as the source I would put the address of the HTML file? As for the rest of the coding, is that kind of required coding? Also, can I use the same code multiple times on the same page to reference multiple different things? Thanks so much, everyone, for putting up with my extreme lack of knowledge. :D

Comment: No, don't do the iframe approach. That basically embeds a little browser thing and it'll confuse you. Go with the <!--#include file="whatever.txt" --> approach. I'll throw that in an answer in case BumbleB2na doesn't update.

Comment: Okay, I'll do That. But, my question still remains: can that support multiple instances on the same page, because I'll want to do that for the majority of the page to make future customization easier.

Comment: Sure. You can have as many include directives on a page as you want, and you can put the same thing in many pages. It's just some pre-processing instructions to the web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<!--#include file="menu.html" -->` is a server side include that will tell the web server you're using to replace everything between `<!--` and `-->` with the contents of the named file.

The example I gave assumes menu.html is in the same directory. If it isn't, you'll need to adjust your path accordingly.

Comment: Thanks so much! It works! However, how would I accommodate if it's not in the same directory? Say, for instance, I have a page buried within a few folders; how would I get it to reference the files that are on the top-level? I know for things like images and css you just have to add the initial forward slash, and that will make it reference it. However, I tried to do that, and it told me there was an error processing the derivative.

Comment: You can either do the `../` style paths to give it a relative path from that directory (although sometimes that's not allowed), or you can do a `<!--#include virtual="menu.html" -->` and give a path from the root of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of server-side scripts let you do this. I'm most familiar with PHP:

```
<?php require("navbar.html"); ?>
```

Inserts the contents of `navbar.html` directly where the `require` call is.

Without any server-side code, however, you'd have to use AJAX to call the file and load it into the right place - if you go this route you should have a container of appropriate size to "reserve" space for when it loads.

Comment: Okay, so all I have to do is post this code in the area I want the section to show up (with my file changed, of course)? No other code is needed?

Comment: Yes, but the file that it's in must be a PHP file, otherwise it won't be processed. And you have to have PHP installed, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that's the whole point of HTML

Use the `<a href="">` tag.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html

---

You can keep the sidebar always updated either by using a server-side template scheme, javascript or iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Use an iframe (update value of `width` to match the pixel width you want for the sidebar):

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" style="border:0;height:100%;width:150px;" scrolling="no">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Comment: That's a server side include. It'll only work if whatever's serving up the web page can process it.

Comment: Oops.. thank you. I think I might have confused that with something similar to a server-side `#include` that web devs used a long time ago on the client-side.

Comment: Ah, but your original answer *will* work for the person asking the question! Can you put it back so I can encourage them to accept your answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP includes, like this from one of my sites:

```
<?php include './includes/YOUR_NAME_HERE.php'; ?>
```

Then put the content of the sidebar in that.

Link: [PHP Includes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)